# $\sum_{n=i}^{j}\frac{1}{n}$ Isn't Integer Without Bertrand's Postulate

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$i,j\in \mathbb{N}$ and $i<j $. Prove that $$\sum_{n=i}^{j}\frac{1}{n}$$ isn't integer using without using the [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Comment: How about when $i=j=1$?

Comment: I have edited the problem to remove this case.